# Replace() yields "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" when used with zero

Tags: javascript, android, mongodb

I'm getting numbers from MongoDb, I parse them to my format by removing any space or comma if exists by using `replace()` method. While this was working perfectly for a while, I just found it is producing the following error when value is zero

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

The snippet that include the questioned method is as follows:

```
function Query_Member_points_credits_summaryExecute() 
{
    var Balance = Apperyio.storage.MS_Member_Points_Credits_Summary.get("$['Balance']");
    var balance = parseFloat(Balance.replace(',', '').replace(' ', ''));
    console.log("balance " + balance);
    var threshold = parseFloat(50000);
    console.log("threshold " + threshold);
}
```

The error caused by the second line.

**Investigation attempts:**

1. I replaced the line with the following:
   a. `var balance = parseFloat(Balance.replace(',', ''));`
   b. `var balance = parseFloat(Balance.replace(' ', ''));`
   c. `var balance = Balance.replace(',', '').replace(' ', '');`
2. Only this has worked with `balance = 0`:
   `var balance = parseFloat(Balance);`
3. Using numbers other than zero, including 0.000001, it is working fine

I'm baffled what could be the reason

Comment: `.replace()` is a **string** method.  If `Balance` is a number, then you cannot call `.replace()` on it.  And, if it's a number, then you don't need to try to remove commas and spaces from it.

Comment: Is there any explanation why it works with any numbers other than zero?

Comment: If you want to understand what's going on, then you will have to insert `console.log(typeof Balance);` right before you do the `.replace()` to see what you have.  `Balance.replace()` will not work if `typeof Balance` is anything other than `"string"`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ok, I understand now. Any number other than zero, typeof alert displays `string`, although the type of the property in the DB is number. Only '0' will remain as `number`. I assume this is appery platform inconsistency.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like an inconsistency.  You can make sure it is a string by doing `("" + Balance).replace(',', '').replace(' ', '')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first suggest, after:

```
var Balance = Apperyio.storage.MS_Member_Points_Credits_Summary.get("$['Balance']");
```

putting in some debug code to tell you what `Balance` actually *is,* something like:

```
alert(typeof(Balance));
```

From your error message, it's possibly `undefined`. If that is the case, then you will need to track down why `appery.io` is giving you an undefined value for zero.

If it's *not* undefined, then it may be some strange type (i.e., not a string) which may affect the pipeline of `replace` calls.

If `appery.io` is giving you a `number` type for zero and a `string` type for non-zero (as per your comment), a quick'n'dirty fix may be something like:

```
// Ensure number made string before replace.
var balance = parseFloat((""+Balance).replace(',', '').replace(' ', ''));
```

Then I'd be contacting them to ask whether this is a bug on their part.

Comment: It is of the type `number`. Since `replace` works only with `string` type, is there any explanation it does not produce this error with any other numeric value except zero?

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Any number other than zero, typeof alert displays `string`. Only '0' will remain as `number`. I assume this is appery platform inconsistency.

Comment: Just to let you know, with `var balance = parseFloat((""+Balance).replace(',', '').replace(' ', ''));` somehow type remained number. I had to use `var balance = parseFloat(toString(Balance).replace(',', '').replace(' ', ''));`. Thanks